# QtAudioOutput запись в файл

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу получать данные из опеределённого аудиопотока и складывать их в файл .raw
Почему-то всегда outputSource.state() = QAudio::IdleState, хотя я подаю аудиосигнал сигнал на данный поток. Соответственно файл пуст.
**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QFile>
#include <QIODevice>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);

void getAudioDevicesList()
{
//    cout << "Input: " << endl;
//    const auto inputDeviceInforms = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);
//    for (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo : inputDeviceInforms)
//        cout << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName() << endl;

    cout << "Output: " << endl;
    const auto outputDeviceInforms = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);
    int outputAmount = 0;
    for (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo : outputDeviceInforms)
        cout << ++outputAmount << ". "<< deviceInfo.deviceName() << endl;

//    int index = 0;
//    cout << "Please write index of prefered output device: ";
//    cin >> index;

    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getAudioDevicesList();
    QFile destinationFile;
    destinationFile.setFileName("C:/Users/Kirill Pukhov/OneDrive/Desktop/test.raw");
    destinationFile.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);

    QAudioDeviceInfo outputDeviceInfo(QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput).takeAt(0));
    cout << "Output device: " << outputDeviceInfo.deviceName() << endl;

    QAudioFormat outputFormat;
    outputFormat.setSampleRate(44100);
    outputFormat.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    outputFormat.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    outputFormat.setSampleSize(16);
    outputFormat.setChannelCount(2);
    outputFormat.setCodec("audio/pcm");

    QAudioOutput outputSource(outputDeviceInfo, outputFormat);
    outputSource.setBufferSize(outputFormat.sampleSize() * outputFormat.channelCount() * 1024);
    QIODevice *outputDevice = outputSource.start();
    outputDevice->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    destinationFile.write(static_cast<char *>(outputDevice->peek(outputFormat.sampleSize() * outputFormat.channelCount() * 1024).data()));

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Это тестовый код, т.к. я ещё только учусь работать с аудио в Qt
Мне кажется, что я что-то с самого начала начал что-то не так делать, т.к. немного не понимаю точно как работают эти классы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй стоит начать с того что QAudioOutput предназначен для ВЫВОДА

> The QAudioOutput class provides an interface for sending audio data to
>   an audio output device

Вам нужен QAudioInput

> The QAudioInput class provides an interface for receiving audio data
>   from an audio input device.

Пример его использования можно посмотреть тут: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audioinput-example.html

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы входным потоком являлся выходной поток(аудиосигнал, поступающий на динаимки)

Comment: Если  я подставляю в QAudioDeviceInfo - QAudioOutput, то в QIODevice мне выдаёт ->openMode() = 33, хотя такого даже не существует(32 = QIODevice::Unbuffered).

Comment: openMode()=33 (0x21) = QIODevice::Unbuffered|QIODevice::ReadOnly (два флага)

Comment: по поводу выход->вход не подскажу. смотрите какие варианты есть QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput)